# Merge two-columns files into one file

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I have a bunch of files (`file1`, `file2`,`file3`, ...) with two columns. For example, `file1` looks like:

```
0.12 0
0.32 0
0.42 1
0.23 0
```

and `file2` looks like:

```
0.34 1
0.55 1
0.31 1
0.99 0
```

I wonder how to properly merge these files to one file with only first columns. The output file should be like:

```
0.12 0.34
0.32 0.55
0.42 0.31
0.23 0.99
```

My initial (unsuccessful) attempt is here:

```
pr -t -s ',' -m <(< file1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1) <(< file2 | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
```

Comment: steve's answer demonstrates that your problem statement is unclear.  Please describe more clearly what you mean by "merge" **and** show two or more sample files (it's probably sufficient to show only two or three lines from each) *and then show the desired output*.  BTW, are you guaranteeing that all the files are the same length (if that's appropriate)?

Comment: BTW, `< ` *`filename `* `| ` *`command`* isn't going to work.  Try `< ` *`filename  command`* (leaving out the `|`) or  *`command `*  `< ` *`filename`* (putting the I/O redirection at the end of the command).

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. The following line works : `pr -t -s' ' -m <(< file1 cut -d ' ' -f 1) <(< file2 cut -d ' ' -f 1 )`

Comment: (The five-minute editing window ran out.)  By the way, `< ` *`filename `* `| ` *`command`* isn't going to work.  Try `< ` *`filename  command`* (omitting the `|`) or *`command `*  `< ` *`filename`* (putting the I/O redirection at the end of the command).  In fact, most commands (including `cut`) will read from file(s) whose name(s) are passed as arguments, so you can say simply *`command `* *`filename`*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the number of files is large, awk sounds like a good choice:

```
awk '
    {line[FNR] = line[FNR] $1 OFS}
    END {for (i=1; i<=FNR; i++) print line[i]}
' file1 file2 file3 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach:

```
$ cat file1
0.12 0
0.32 0
0.42 1
0.23 0
$ cat file2
0.92 0
0.92 0
0.92 1
0.93 0
$ cat file1 file2 | cut -f1 -d" "
0.12
0.32
0.42
0.23
0.92
0.92
0.92
0.93
$
```

Comment: I need to add new files by columns.